# The classic falling rope problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

A rope was on top of a table with a part of it hanging off the edge, without any friction.
The equation of the motion is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{mgx}{L}=m \frac{dx^2}{dt^2} \to \ddot{x}=\frac{gx}{L}
\end{equation}
In which $x$ is the length of rope hanging over the edge of the table, and the $L$ is the total length of the rope.

My question is: why is the tension force not considered? Since, the rope that is still on top of the table, needs a force to start it's movement, and I was thinking that this force should be considered on the vertical part of the rope as well.

If we think in a similar problem, in which there is two cubes connected by an ideal rope and a pulley, and one of them is hanging off the table, the tension should be considered. But, in the case that is just the rope (with mass), there is no traction, and I want to know why?

Comment: please, add a sketch representing the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tension force is not relevant because we are considering the motion of the chain (mass $m$) as a whole, but the tension is internal to the chain, that is if one part, A, of the chain exerts a force $\mathbf F$ on another part, B, then B exerts a force $-\mathbf F$ on A so there is no resultant force on the chain as a whole due to tension.

Things are a little more complicated at the edge of the table, where the chain bends through a right angle. [The edge of the table may be taken as shaped like a quarter-circle in section.] While it is true that the vertical and horizontal parts of the chain exert forces of equal magnitude on each other, we cannot justify this from Newton's third law, as the forces are at right angles to each other. A full analysis would include the normal contact force of the table-edge on the chain, but would lead to the same result: the vertical and horizontal parts of the chain exert forces of equal magnitude on each other.

Comment: But the part of the rope that is on top of the table. How does it start it's moviment since there is no force on the x axis? I was thinking that force should be the tension.

Comment: It is the tension force that accelerates the part of the rope that lies on the table, but your equation considers the chain as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is discussed [here](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.12817) and [here](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.17442), along with the various incorrect solutions, including the one you suggest.

Comment: I truly didn't understand what the article has to do with the traction. I just understanded that the rope won't slide of the table on its corner like the problem sugested, but the problem of the traction is still unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by the "traction force"? Do you mean the tension in the string?

Comment: Yes, that's it, the tension force. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those links gives anything more than access to an abstract. Would you be able to incorporate the essentials in your answer?

Comment: "the various incorrect solutions, **including the one you suggest**" Do you mean $\ddot x=\frac gl x$?

Comment: The solution suggested by the OP is equivalent to the one given in Thorton's solutions manual to his classical dynamics textbook. It's not incorrect, but one must account under what conditions it follows, which may be what answers the OP's question itself.

Comment: @ Johann Wagner.  Yes, that's what I meant. The actual physical situation is more complicated than implied by the answer.  Assuming that the string is constrained to be an inverted "L" you  can get that from Lagrange with ${\rm Langrange}=T-V$. I do not understand what is bothering the OP though. The tension is a constraint force, and irrelevent for the bulk motion.